# Why can not release semaphore in barrier's action

Tags: python, concurrency, action, semaphore, barrier

It's a problem to create H2O from H and O.
The input guarentee's that H is always double of O.
There are threads to produce H and threads to produce O.
 We must make sure H and O are combined to H2O.
Here is the link of problem: [leetcode 1117. Building H2O](https://leetcode.com/problems/building-h2o/)

the code below works

```
from threading import Barrier,Semaphore

class H2O:
    def __init__(self):
        self.osm, self.hsm=Semaphore(1), Semaphore(2)
        self.b=Barrier(3)

    def hydrogen(self, releaseHydrogen: 'Callable[[], None]') -> None:
        self.hsm.acquire()
        # releaseHydrogen() outputs "H". Do not change or remove this line.
        releaseHydrogen()
        self.b.wait()
        self.hsm.release()



    def oxygen(self, releaseOxygen: 'Callable[[], None]') -> None:
        self.osm.acquire()
        # releaseOxygen() outputs "O". Do not change or remove this line.
        releaseOxygen()
        self.b.wait()
        self.osm.release()
```

But if I change the code like this:

```
from threading import Barrier,Semaphore

class H2O:
    def __init__(self):
        self.osm, self.hsm=Semaphore(1), Semaphore(2)
        self.b=Barrier(3, action=action)

    def hydrogen(self, releaseHydrogen: 'Callable[[], None]') -> None:
        self.hsm.acquire()
        # releaseHydrogen() outputs "H". Do not change or remove this line.
        releaseHydrogen()
        self.b.wait()


    def oxygen(self, releaseOxygen: 'Callable[[], None]') -> None:
        self.osm.acquire()
        # releaseOxygen() outputs "O". Do not change or remove this line.
        releaseOxygen()
        self.b.wait()

    def action(self):
        self.osm.release()
        self.hsm.release()
        self.hsm.release()
```

It can not work!
Why I can not release semaphore in barrier's action?